# Apply the lambda function for replacing number in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

What's the good way to replace the number into pandas pivot table?

I used this code but always invalid syntax. What's the syntax should be? for replacing number in pivot.

[image]

I would like to perform when number in table greater than or equals 2.5 would return 1 and if less than 2.5 return 0.

```
pivot_table.fillna(-1).apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 2.5 else 0)
```

Please advise.

Comment: Show us the whole error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon the error most likely is `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`

Comment: Don't use `.apply` for something like `.apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 2.5 else 0)`, use vectorized solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
(pivot_table > 2.5).astype(int)
```

Comment: I might don't understand. Could you please show some example?